# How To Apply Different Styles To All Blocks Based on Post Meta Value?

Tags: hooks, block-editor

I'm looking for a way to pass post meta data to each of the blocks in the editor for the purpose of styling the content. My actual use case is hard to explain briefly, but for the sake of example, pretend it's the ability to display the post either in dark or light mode depending on a post meta value that the user sets.

The most obvious way to do this, for me, would be to add a class to the `<div class="block-editor">` element like `<div class="block-editor dark-editor-mode">`. But I don't see an obvious way to do that. Everything I find via search is about modifying the individual blocks, but I want to modify the editor. Is there a hook for this? Either in JS or PHP?

Comment: I don't believe you need this to do what you're trying to achieve. CSS can handle all of this, you just need to put a toggle in a sidebar somewhere to control dark/light. Even then, I'd still say the solution here is actually composition, aka a containing block that's dark, or a containing block that's light. Otherwise you would fetch the meta from within the block, you wouldn't give it to the block

Comment: Also, if you're going to show posts filtered by dark/light, this should be a term not a post meta for performance reasons

Comment: As I said in my question, the dark/light is just an example, and the real use case has nothing to do with dark/light mode, but is too complicated to explain in the context of this question.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is to apply different styles depending on the value of a the post meta. And no, it's not possible to do that only with CSS if there is no class in the HTML for the CSS selectors to use, and no variable being passed to the CSS.

Comment: Regarding the use of a containing block, if you can provide an answer for how to wrap the entire post editor in a containing block that has the post meta value as a class name, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Here's another example, for clarity. Say I have a post meta field called "show_unicorns" that users can toggle true/false to show unicorn animations on any page of their blog. On the front end, I can query that post meta in the content to inject the unicorn animations with some fancy CSS. But if I want to add those unicorn animations in the Gutenberg editor, only when the post meta has `show_unicorns=true`, I need a way for all of the blocks in the editor to know the value of the post meta.

Comment: The block based way would be to either wrap all the blocks in a wrapper block e.g. a "Unicons" container block, aka the composition solution, otherwise I'd need to know more about your problem. For example your last comment implies all these blocks are blocks you built, if so, then that implies a number of solutions that wouldn't work if you were talking about blocks from plugins you did not build yourself. Also consider that by trying to genericize the problem, you've hemmed yourself into this particular style of solution, when an alternative way of approaching things might be possible

Comment: For example, in some situations, the answer might be to use block styles, or a feature you were unaware of in order to achive something. But if you've decided that the only way to solve that problem is through solution Y, then genericised solution Y to arrive at the question, then the much easier solution Z is hidden from you as a result. Without more detail, the canonical answer to this at the moment is *"it depends"* :( Also, when you say style, do you mean CSS style? Or is this controlling attributes? Changing markup? That part of the Q was ambiguous

Comment: There are a number of ways I could word the question, and of course I'm open to hearing any solution that would work.

The blocks are core blocks that I'm extending with a custom functionality. I'm aware of block styles, but I'm not creating another style, but rather modifying the styles that exist. The result would be that every existing block style has my custom functionality added.

The canonical answer I'm looking for is how I get a post meta data value from the wp.data store and use it in an editor stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using the `admin_body_class` filter to add a class name to the `<body>` element of the admin page, and writing selectors for that class in my stylesheet.

```php
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'add_status_classes' );
```

```php
function add_status_classes( $classes ) {
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
  $is_darkmode = $post_meta['_is_post_dark_mode'];
  if ( $is_darkmode ) {
    $classes = $classes . ' dark-editor-mode';
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

```css
/* Normal Styles */
p:after {
  content: "Walking on sunshine!";
}
/* Styles when custom post meta option is true */
.dark-editor-mode p {
  content: "It sure is dark in here!";
}
```

Again, the dark mode is just a simple example, since my real use case is too complex to explain here, but the concept is the same.

Unfortunately, the drawback of this solution is that the editor has to be refreshed after the user changes the post meta setting, since the class isn't tied to a JavaScript store. If anyone knows how to hook into a data store that controls a classname on a parent element to the editor panel in Gutenberg, please add to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Your proposed solution is not possible.** There is no hook or filter that would allow you to apply a CSS class to the block list or the styles wrapper div, and no means to insert one.

*This appears to be intentional*, and also runs contrary to how things would work going forward, or how blocks in general work ( how would this work inside if the post meta was present in a reusable block post, or a site footer rather than a page/post? ).

Your next step if you absolutely must take this route, is to open a feature request in the github issues for the gutenberg repo, or write a pull request.

You can very easily just wait until the editor is initialised and grab the post meta from the data store, but there's no way to set a HTML class to apply the styling at an editor level.

Alternatives include:

- Using your own custom blocks, and checking the post meta via the data store for each block
- Using a containing block with child blocks, where the child blocks are then styled according to the settings of the parent block ( this also allows the post meta to be eliminated entirely, and futureproofs the functionality for full site editing and reusable blocks )
- Using block styles ( perhaps bulk setting of block styles is an equivalent to what you want to achieve? )

Comment: I have a solution, but since you so confidently told me it's not possible, and my question is "contrary to how things work", I guess I'm wrong.

Comment: If you have an answer, I'd like to hear it, please post it as an answer. My answers based on searching through the Gutenberg code base looking for hooks to add classes to the editor style wrap div